# How to create a manual trigger for multiple parallel jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to have a blocking manual action that will trigger multiple parallel jobs in the next stage. How can I achieve this? For example:

1. deploy-int runs on merge
2. The pipeline waits on a single manual trigger
3. deploy-prd-1 and deploy-prd-2 run in parallel

Here's what I've tried:

## 1

```
stages:
  - deploy-dev
  - deploy-prd-1
  - deploy-prd-2

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  script:
    - echo deploy-dev

deploy-prd-1:
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  stage: deploy-prd-1
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-1

deploy-prd-2:
  stage: deploy-prd-2
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-2
```

This achieves 1 and 2, but fails on 3, as deploy-prd-1 and deploy-prd-2 are in series, not parallel

## 2

```
stages:
  - deploy-dev
  - deploy-prd

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  script:
    - echo deploy-dev

deploy-prd-1:
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  stage: deploy-prd
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-1

deploy-prd-2:
  stage: deploy-prd
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-2
```

This fails on 2, as deploy-prd-2 will run automatically without waiting on the manual trigger

## 3

```
stages:
  - deploy-dev
  - deploy-prd

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  script:
    - echo deploy-dev

deploy-prd-1:
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  stage: deploy-prd
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-1

deploy-prd-2:
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  stage: deploy-prd
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-2
```

This isn't ideal as it requires manually triggering *each* parallel job separately.

## 4

```
stages:
  - deploy-dev
  - approve
  - deploy-prd

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  script:
    - echo deploy-dev

approve:
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

deploy-prd-1:
  stage: deploy-prd
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-1

deploy-prd-2:
  stage: deploy-prd
  script:
    - echo deploy-prd-2
```

This is my attempt to set up a manual "gate", but gitlab rejects the file with `Error: jobs:approve script can't be blank`.
I can set a no-op like `script: [":"]`, but now gitlab will spin up a container to do nothing, which wastes time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming the reason you want a manual gate is because you want to do some testing before you publish your app.

Instead of doing everything in a single go, a change in mindset might work better.

Use the gitlab ci rules keyword to make each of the two groups of jobs to run on their own schedule (these can have their times turned off, so they become a manual trigger requiring you to push a button).

Then break your ci down, where you build and deploy to your dev environment first. Do your tests and then when you are happy trigger the deploy to prod jobs.